# Font awesome icons not aligning correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I have these div below taht have a font swesome icon with a circle around them. But they aren't aligned correclty as the width aren't the same, so the text isn't vertically aligned.

Can this be fixed, I remember some class that I could use to fix it, but don't remember the class name.

```css
.circle-icon {
    background: #e3f4f6;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg rating-color mr-2 circle-icon mb-2" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> <span>{{member.reviews}} Like<ng-container *ngIf="member.reviews > 1">s</ng-container> </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span><i class="fa fa-star fa-lg rating-color mr-2 circle-icon mb-2" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> <span>{{member.reviews}} Review<ng-container *ngIf="member.reviews > 1">s</ng-container> </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span><i class="fa fa-check fa-lg rating-color mr-2 circle-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> <span>Verified</span>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use stacking icons: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/stacking-icons

```css
.fa-circle {
  color: #e3f4f6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0c7c27ff53.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div>
  <span class="fa-stack fa-1x">
  <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-user fa-stack-1x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 </span>
  <span>10 Likes</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="fa-stack fa-1x">
  <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-star fa-stack-1x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span> <span>8 Reviews </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="fa-stack fa-1x">
  <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-check fa-stack-1x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span> <span>Verified</span>
</div>
```

Works also with the CSS version:

```css
.fa-circle {
  color: #e3f4f6;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">

<div>
  <span class="fa-stack fa-1x">
  <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-user fa-stack-1x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 </span>
  <span>10 Likes</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="fa-stack fa-1x">
  <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-star fa-stack-1x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span> <span>8 Reviews </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="fa-stack fa-1x">
  <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-check fa-stack-1x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span> <span>Verified</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @user1186050 no it won't ... I advise to move to the V5, the V4 is too old now. V6 is already on the road and will be released in the next months

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the width atribute and give every cricle-icon the same width.